# Rolling 12 month Calculation SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a 12 month rolling calculation, but I get a syntax error at "rows", here is what I have so far:

```
(SUM(YTDValue) OVER (ORDER BY PerformanceDate ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) / 12 AS Yearly_YTDValue
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql , oracle, postgres, snowflake, teradata, mariadb, sqlite, etc)?

Comment: Hi, It is Sql server management studio 18

Answer (score 0):

It might be your RDMBS doesn't support that syntax, because at first glance it looks correct to me.

This method will only work if you are guaranteed to have exactly 12 `PerformanceDates`, so sometimes I prefer this method because it does not require me to aggregate the data to monthly levels first.

```
WITH BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY AS (
  SELECT 
    A.DATE, 
    SUM(B.YTDValue) as Yearly_YTDValue
  FROM 
    UserActivity A 
    JOIN UserActivity B
  WHERE 
    B.DATE >= DATEADD(year, -12, A.DATE) 
    AND B.DATE <= A.DATE 
  GROUP BY A.DATE
) 
SELECT 
  src.*, 
  BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY.Yearly_YTDValue 
FROM 
  UserActivity src 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY ON BASIC_OFFSET_7DAY.DATE = src.DATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using SQL server management studio 18. I have done something similar before and it has worked fine. ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number, MONTH(perioddate) ORDER BY perioddate DESC) This works for me in a different query

Comment: @arsenaql if you just try SUM(YTDValue) OVER (ORDER BY PerformanceDate ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) does it work, and if not what is the exact error regarding 'rows' ?

Comment: Hi, yeah still get an error. "Incorrect syntax near rows"